Is there any ways for me to build tracking link which includes UTM parameters directly in the Google Play App's link?
I had set up a Google Ads campaign and used Google Play App's link as a final URL. Can i ask that is there any ways for me to build tracking link which includes UTM parameters directly in the Google Play App's link?  If it can be created, can I track traffic data from this tracking link on Google Analytics?
I had found tool Google Play URL Builder, but I don't know if it can be worked; I am still a junior digital executive so I have come here to ask more experienced people in a hope of success
